# PHP: cUrling in Aweber

Tags: php, curl

Did anyone here manage to curl in aweber?

Thanks!

Comment: Er, what? AWeber appears to be a hosted e-mail marketing platform. How would you use PHP in that?

Answer (score 2):

yeah, however its useless, as after some form submissions they will block your account because email subscriptions etc need to come from the client ip and not a fixed site ip. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I wanted to automate my messages' content or my auto responder. I have some offers and sometimes it goes away without me noticing, so I need to change that expired offer whenever it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Aweber provides an API https://labs.aweber.com/ which you can use to add subscribers etc, most likely what you were doing with the curl I assume.

Plus it wont get your IP blocked!